# bit masks and shift operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a question regarding bit masks and shift operator in C

```
uint32_t reg_val = 0xffffffff;

if(1 == ((reg_val & BIT12)>>12))
{
     //DO SOMETHING.
}
```

where BIT12 is (1 <<12).
The question is whether the right shift by 12 is really necessary.If not is it because the logical value of the expression (reg_val&BIT12) is '1' if BIT12 is set in reg_val and '0' if BIT12 is cleared in reg_val?Also is it a recommended coding practice to do the shift from a readability point of view.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unecessary

```
if (reg_val & BIT12)   // would be sufficient
{
     //DO SOMETHING.
}
```

Now, the above works because BIT12 is assumed to have only one non-zero bit .  A more generic way to handle this kind of test would be

```
if ((reg_val & BIT12) == BIT12)  
{
     //DO SOMETHING.
}
```

The reason for this is that the first snippet only tests if reg_val AND-ed with BIT12 is non-zero (i.e. reg_val and BIT12 have at least one non-zero bit in common).  The second snippet tests that all the bits which are set in BIT12 are also set in reg_val.

Answer (score 2):

The right shift is necessary because the result of the `&` will be `1<<12`, and you're comparing to 1 which is `1<<0`.

Instead of comparing to 1, you can compare to *not 0* (i.e.: `0 !=...`), and then skip the right shift.

Answer (score 1):

The right shift by 12 isn't necessary, but it's nice because you can compare it with 1 instead of 4096 (harder to remember and to tell exactly what the code is doing) but since you've got `BIT12` there already it's OK to use that instead.

Comment: @Michael: Right XD I remember thinking: "But it's base-zero, so 2 to the power of 11, don't mess up on that :)"

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly write 

`if (0 != reg_val & BIT12) ...`

or

`if (BIT12 == reg_val & BIT12) ...`